# How to create multiple custom picture libraries from Visual studio 2012?

Tags: custom-list, visual-studio-2012, picture-library

Here I am creating multiple custom pucture libraries from the visual studio for that I  followed many articles. [this](http://sharepointwiththili.blogspot.in/2015/01/create-custom-picture-library-with-list.html) is one of them.
This one is very usefull while creating a single library and I got issue when I am creating multiple libraries by following the same article.
here for each picture library I have some custom columns which I am adding from visual studio itself as like below image.
[image]
I have added this column to my first library.
and now I am creating another Picture library by following the same article as per above Link. and to this library I am not Adding any custom column.
After deploying my solution I am seeing this **Alternate Text** column(this is custom column) in both libraries while I am adding that to first library only.
here I am trying to get rid of this issue but I am unable to get the solution.